# How to delete Component(s) from a JIRA issue with scriptrunner?

Tags: groovy, jira

I'm trying to remove components from a JIRA issue via ScriptRunner from a Post Function. I tried to do it in different ways, but non of it works:

```
Collection<GenericValue> col =  issue.componentObjects.asCollection()
log.debug logPref + "Deleting: " + issue.componentObjects.removeAll(col)
log.debug logPref + "Deleting: " + col.removeAll([null])
```

First line returns true, second one removes false, but anyway components are on their place. 
Also tried:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.component.ProjectComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
def projectComponentManager = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(ProjectComponentManager)
projectComponentManager.updateIssueProjectComponents(issue, [])
```

But get:

```
No signature of method: com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.component.DefaultProjectComponentManager.updateIssueProjectComponents() is applicable for argument types: (com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueImpl, java.util.ArrayList) values: [IID-44017, []]
```

Following:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.JiraServiceContextImpl
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.component.ProjectComponentService
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor



def jiraServiceContext = new JiraServiceContextImpl(ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getUser().getDirectoryUser())
issue.getComponentObjects().each { it ->
    ComponentAccessor.getComponent(ProjectComponentService).deleteComponentForIssues(jiraServiceContext, it.id)
}
```

Hangs my JIRA instance and throws:

```
2016-09-15 14:09:38,727 http-bio-8080-exec-19 WARN viktork 848x207x1 d9pyfm 10.30.0.198 /secure/CommentAssignIssue.jspa [jira.notification.type.UserCFValue] Exception occurred while working out recipients from a custom field value. Returning empty list.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no ID mapped for the user key 'pmo lead'
    at com.atlassian.jira.user.DefaultUserPropertyManager.getPropertySetForUserKey(DefaultUserPropertyManager.java:47)
    at com.atlassian.jira.user.DefaultUserPropertyManager.getPropertySet(DefaultUserPropertyManager.java:31)
    at com.atlassian.jira.user.preferences.DefaultUserPreferencesManager.getExtendedPreferences(DefaultUserPreferencesManager.java:28)
    at com.atlassian.jira.notification.NotificationRecipient.getFormatPreference(NotificationRecipient.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.jira.notification.NotificationRecipient.<init>(NotificationRecipient.java:66)
```

Does anyone have a working method? My JIRA version is 6.4.7

Answer (score 0):

Execute in post function before anything is written into DB:

```
issue.setComponentObjects([])
```